# watch aliased cmd doesn't work

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

When I do

```
$ watch kubectl get pods
```

it works fine but on doing:

```
$ alias p0="kubectl get pods"
$ watch p0
```

gives an error:
    Every 2.0s: p0
    sh: p0: command not found

It looks like watch is starting a subshell and the aliases in my current shell aren't visible to the subshell. I do have

```
$ shopt -s expand_aliases
```

at the very top of my .bashrc but it isn't helping.

Trying this with bash version 3.2.57 on Mac OS Mojave.

Update:
Tried a few more things:

```
$  watch -n 0.1 "source ~/.bashrc; shopt; alias p0; p0"
```

still doesn't work.

```
cdable_vars     off
cdspell         off
checkhash       off
checkwinsize    off
cmdhist         on
compat31        off
dotglob         off
execfail        off
expand_aliases  on
extdebug        off
extglob         off
extquote        on
failglob        off
force_fignore   on
gnu_errfmt      off
histappend      on
histreedit      off
histverify      off
hostcomplete    on
huponexit       off
interactive_comments    on
lithist         off
login_shell     off
mailwarn        off
no_empty_cmd_completion off
nocaseglob      off
nocasematch     off
nullglob        off
progcomp        on
promptvars      on
restricted_shell        off
shift_verbose   off
sourcepath      on
xpg_echo        on
p0='kubectl get pods'   <--- HERE'S THE ALIAS
sh: p0: command not found  <--- STILL DOESN'T EXECUTE IT.
```

Answer (score 4):

Aliases are not inherited by subshells. Functions may be exported but while this approach makes Bash inherit exported function(s) from Bash, `watch` will interfere, mainly because it spawns `sh`, not `bash`.

You have at least three options:

1. Make `p0` a script somewhere in `$PATH`, so `watch` can run it like any other executable. If done right, this will be very robust.
2. Define a special alias for `watch`:

   ```
   alias watch='watch '
   ```

   Then this happens:

   > If the last character of the alias value is a blank, then the next command word following the alias is also checked for alias expansion.

   <sup>[source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases)</sup>

   So `watch p0` will work (but `watch -n 4 p0` won't).
3. Define an alias (or function, or script, whatever) for the whole command:

   ```
   alias wp0='watch kubectl get pods'
   ```

   and type just `wp0`.

Comment: Great answer @Kamil. Reg. your first answer, I could make it a script. However, I have hundreds of aliases collected over the years and making them individual scripts seems like a lot of work.

Comment: +1 on yr 2nd point. Been using aliases for yrs w/o ever having come across that nugget.

Answer (score 1):

```
function watcha() {
    a=$(alias $1) # extract the cmd from the alias

    #remove = sign and first/last ' before executing thru watch
    watch $(echo $a | awk -F= '{print $2}'|sed 's/.$//'|sed 's/^.//') 
}
```

Now when I do

```
$ watcha p0
```

it does work as expected.

Comment: `alias watcha='watch '` seems more robust and so much simpler.